# Jcombobox not selecting item

Tags: java, database, sqlite, user-interface

Im trying to insert the Jcombobox value into my sqlite database but whenever I run the program, it only inserts '9' in to my database. Please advise. I am trying to import the integer that the user picks into my sqlite database. For some reason, even with the action listener, the default value, 9, is still being inputed into the table and im not sure why. Here is the full code, not including the connection and the Jtable.

```
public class create extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                create frame = new create();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
    Connection connect = null;
    private JTextField textField_2;

    String uniqueString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private JTextField textField_3;


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public create() {
    connect = connection.dbConnector();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblStudentName = new JLabel("Student ID:");
    lblStudentName.setBounds(96, 69, 72, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblStudentName);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(173, 64, 216, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblGrade = new JLabel("Grade:");
    lblGrade.setBounds(125, 107, 47, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblGrade);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem(9);
    comboBox.addItem(10);
    comboBox.addItem(11);
    comboBox.addItem(12);
    comboBox.setBounds(173, 102, 72, 29);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(9); 
    comboBox.addActionListener(comboBox); 
    int selectedNumber = (int)comboBox.getSelectedItem();

    JLabel lblInputBookOver = new JLabel("Teacher:");
    lblInputBookOver.setBounds(111, 146, 61, 21);
    contentPane.add(lblInputBookOver);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(173, 143, 216, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JButton button = new JButton("<");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int count = 0; count <= 0; count++) {
                //dispose();
                options sc = new options();
                sc.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
    button.setBounds(6, 6, 30, 29);
    contentPane.add(button);

    JLabel lblStudentname = new JLabel("Student Name:");
    lblStudentname.setBounds(74, 31, 99, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblStudentname);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(173, 26, 216, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
    lblEmail.setBounds(125, 180, 42, 26);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(173, 180, 216, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnCheckout = new JButton("Checkout");
    btnCheckout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final String uniqueString = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

            try {
                String query = "insert into data ('Name', 'Student ID', 'Teacher', 'Grade', 'Email', 'Ebook') values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1,textField_2.getText() );
                pst.setString(2,textField.getText() );
                pst.setString(3,textField_1.getText() );
                pst.setInt(4, selectedNumber);
                pst.setString(5,textField_3.getText() );
                pst.setString(6, uniqueString);

                for (int count = 0; count <= 0; count++) {
                    //dispose();
                    confirm sc = new confirm();
                    sc.setVisible(true);
                    count = 0;
                    }

                pst.execute();                  
                pst.close();

            }

            catch (Exception w){
                w.printStackTrace();

            }   
        }
    });
    btnCheckout.setBounds(173, 218, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnCheckout);


}
}
```

Comment: The default "selected item" of a `DefaultComboBoxModel` when nothing has been selected, is the first one (`selectedObject = getElementAt(0)` ). In your code, no item has been selected.

Comment: I see, so the 9 is just the default value. I should put "selectedObject = getElementAt( 0 )" where? Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It inserts 9 to your database because the selected item is always 9, and this because you add it first to your combobox. In order to insert the selected value, you will have to use an [ActionListener.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) Then you can take user's selection and do whatever you want.

An example of its usage:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ComboBox extends JFrame {

    public ComboBox() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Integer[] numbers = { 4, 5, 8, 123, 42, 634 };
        JComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(numbers);
        comboBox.setSelectedItem(42); // The initial selection is 42.
        comboBox.addActionListener(e -> {
            int selectedNumber = (int) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("Selected number: " + selectedNumber);
            // Do whatever with selected number
        });
        add(comboBox);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ComboBox().setVisible(true));
    }

}
```

Comment: i made the edits but it still doesnt seem to work. Thanks for the input so far

Comment: i just updated everything. Thank you for helping I am still a beginner to all of this